# Formatting css styles

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, css, formatting

I have large css file that contains css rule format like this:

```
.rounded-block
{
   border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
   width: 500px;
   margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
}
```

I need format this file like this

```
.rounded-block{border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;width: 500px;margin: 15px 0 15px 0;}
```

How can I do this?I can do this in visual studio?

Edit:
I need that the other rule will be in another line

```
.rounded-block{border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;width: 500px;margin: 15px 0 15px 0;}
.anotherrule{margin: 15px;}
```

Comment: http://cssminifier.com/

Comment: This cssminifier conver all my styles in one line,but i need other rule will be in another line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these URL for CSS beautifier and to optimize:

[cssbeautify](http://cssbeautify.com/)
[fwpolice](http://html.fwpolice.com/css/)
In there you can define your own rule:

[codebeautifier](http://www.codebeautifier.com/).